# Software for conformational search

Tags: computational-chemistry, conformers

I need a free software to perform a conformational search on molecules with 10 to 16 rotational bonds. What software would you recommend me? Where can I download it? Where can I find a manual of this software?

Comment: It is easy to generate the conformations, and hard to evaluate them by some measure. What property of the conformation are you trying to optimize?

Comment: While not free Spartan is very good and I think worth the price

Comment: Avogadro, Openbabel, RDKit